# How to write query for this using between in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How to write query for this result?

I need output of `EXP_POINT` value in between with find middle value of this `PKT_NO` wise. Means that near by value find.

[image]

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE_MAIN T1
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT * FROM TABLE_SUB xT2
    WHERE T2.PKT_NO = xT2.PKT_NO 
    AND xT2.EXP_POINT BETWEEN T1.EXP_POINT-0.100 AND T1.EXP_POINT + 0.100
)EX
```

I tired this query but I am not getting proper result.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Do you need the middle one of 3 (and are there always 3??) or do you need the one with the closest value for EXT_POINT?

Comment: What result is expected if there aren't 3 rows in table_sub with same pkt_no?

Comment: Sir, in sub table no limit of parent related value more  3 value comes in.

Comment: what will do if it has 6 values ?? which one will take ?

Comment: Specify middle value: is it a mean, is it a median? I reckon it is the median, can you confirm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution assumes that there can be any number of rows in `TABLE_SUB`. I have assumed that when you specify the middle row, that you mean that the rows are sorted by `EXT_POINT`, if this is not what you need you will have to amend the `ORDER BY` clause of the `PARTITION` statement in the `RowOrderPerPkt CTE`.

If there are an odd number of rows then it takes the middle row per `PKT`.

If there are an even number of rows then it takes the middle two rows per `PKT` and takes the average of them.

So here it is:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/393a5/3)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE_MAIN (PKT INT,EXT DECIMAL(10,3))

INSERT INTO TABLE_MAIN (PKT,EXT)
  VALUES  (1101,0.508), (1102,1.998), (1103,0.423)

CREATE TABLE TABLE_SUB (PKT INT,EXT DECIMAL(10,3))

INSERT INTO TABLE_SUB (PKT,EXT)
  VALUES (1101,0.504), (1101,0.505), (1101,0.510)
        ,(1102,1.990), (1102,1.995), (1102,2.005)
        ,(1103,0.504), (1103,0.505), (1103,0.510), (1103,1.990)
```

**Query 1**:

```
;WITH RowOrderPerPkt
AS
(
    SELECT PKT, EXT, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PKT ORDER BY EXT) AS RN
    FROM TABLE_SUB
),
NumRowsPerPkt
AS
(
    SELECT PKT, COUNT(*)  AS MaxRows
    FROM TABLE_SUB
    GROUP BY PKT
)
-- TABLE_SUB with an odd number of rows per PKT
-- Simply take the middle row
-- i.e. MaxRows / 2 + 1
SELECT T1.PKT, T1.EXT, ROPP.EXT 
FROM TABLE_MAIN T1
INNER JOIN RowOrderPerPkt ROPP
    ON ROPP.PKT = T1.PKT
INNER JOIN NumRowsPerPkt NRPP
    ON NRPP.PKT = ROPP.PKT
WHERE NRPP.MaxRows % 2 = 1 AND 
      ROPP.RN = NRPP.MaxRows / 2 + 1
UNION
-- TABLE_SUB with an even number of rows per PKT
-- Simply take the middle 2 rows and find the average
-- i.e. get the rows MaxRows / 2 and MaxRows / 2 + 1
SELECT T1.PKT, T1.EXT, AVG(ROPP.EXT)
FROM TABLE_MAIN T1
INNER JOIN RowOrderPerPkt ROPP
    ON ROPP.PKT = T1.PKT
INNER JOIN NumRowsPerPkt NRPP
    ON NRPP.PKT = ROPP.PKT
WHERE NRPP.MaxRows % 2 = 0  
    AND (ROPP.RN = NRPP.MaxRows / 2 OR ROPP.RN = NRPP.MaxRows /2 + 1)
GROUP BY T1.PKT, T1.Ext
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/393a5/3/0)**:

```
|  PKT |   EXT |    EXT |
|------|-------|--------|
| 1101 | 0.508 |  0.505 |
| 1102 | 1.998 |  1.995 |
| 1103 | 0.423 | 0.5075 |
```

Comment: Hi, This is good ans for me but I have min 20000 pkt's so Its take a too much time and getting time-out error from front side.

Comment: In your result third one row . 0.5075  this value not in your SUB tables. so this is not a right result. i don't want new value i just want to find near by value from sub table.

Comment: @RajuuParmar unfortunately if there are an even number of rows in the SUB table there is no middle value. I stated in the answer that I chose to take the mean of the two closest rows as you hadn't stated how to resolve the situation. Indeed in maths this is the generally accepted mechanism for finding the median value!

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @t table (PKT INT,EXT DECIMAL(10,3))
insert into @t (PKT,EXT)values (1101,0.508),(1102,1.998)

declare @tt table (PKT INT,EXT DECIMAL(10,3))
insert into @tt (PKT,EXT)values (1101,0.504),(1101,0.505),(1101,0.510),(1102,1.990),(1102,1.995),(1102,2.005)

select * from @t T
CROSS APPLY (select ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY PKT ORDER BY EXT  )RN, PKT,EXT FROm @tt )TT
WHERE T.PKT = TT.PKT AND TT.RN = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want only one value, then you need to use `TOP`, preferably with `ORDER BY`.  This should do what you want:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE_MAIN T1 CROSS APPLY
     (SELECT TOP 1 *
      FROM TABLE_SUB T2
       WHERE T1.PKT_NO = T2.PKT_NO AND
             T2.EXP_POINT BETWEEN T1.EXP_POINT-0.100 AND T1.EXP_POINT + 0.100
      ORDER BY ABS(T2.EXP_POINT - T1.EXP_POINT)
     ) EX;
```